# cake php nested query inside a query condition

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I need to build a nested query inside a query condition.

```
    $wc = {"Structure.deleted":0,"StructureSub.code":"YV360"}
    $this->Structure->bindUser();
    $this->Structure->bindSubscriptions();
    $n = $this->Structure->find('count', array('conditions' => $wc));
```

where the models are this way (Model Class `Structure.php`)

```
public function bindSubscriptions($options=array()) {

    $options_default = array(
        'conditions' => array('deleted'=>0),
        'order' => array('created desc')
    );

    $options = array_merge($options_default,$options);

    $this->bindModel(array(
        'hasMany' => array(
            'StructureSub' => $options
        )
    ));

    return $this;
}

public function bindUser($options=array()) {

    $options_default = array(
        'conditions' => array('User.deleted'=>0),
        'foreignKey' => 'owner'
    );

    $options = array_merge($options_default,$options);

    $this->bindModel(array(
        'belongsTo' => array(
            'User' => $options
        )
    ));

    return $this;
}
```

But the query is executed with an error:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'StructureSub.code' in 'where clause'

SQL Query: SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `db`.`structure` AS `Structure` LEFT JOIN `db`.`user` AS `User` ON (`Structure`.`owner` = `User`.`id` AND `User`.`deleted` = 0) WHERE `Structure`.`deleted` = 0 AND `StructureSub`.`code` = 'YV360'
```

`StructureSub` have the field named "`code`" in the db. I don't know why `User`  table is included as join while `StructureSub` is not (I mean calling bind methods). 
Maybe is because some of rows doesn't have relations?

My version of Cake php is `2.5.6`

Comment: Read the damned error message. It clearly says, there your table dos not have a column for `StructureSub` table.

Comment: StructureSub has the field named "code" in the db. I don't know why User related table is automatically included in the query while StructureSub is not.

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version (last line in vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt or lib/Cake/VERSION.txt)